# How to link (t, x) plot and (x, y) plot in Bokeh?

Tags: python, plot, selection, bokeh, interactive

I am measuring two variables, x and y, as a function of time t. I am visualizing this with Bokeh, in scatter plots of x and y as a function of t 
 (plots 1,2) and a third scatter plot of y as a function of x (plot3). I would like the zoom of the (x, y)-plot to follow the zoom of the first two plots. This is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot

t = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=10, freq='H')
x = np.linspace(0, 5, len(t))
y = x**2
source = ColumnDataSource({'t': t, 'x': x, 'y': y})
tools = "pan, box_select, box_zoom, reset"


p1 = figure(tools=tools, x_axis_type='datetime')
p1.scatter(x='t', y='x', source=source)
p2 = figure(tools=tools, x_axis_type='datetime')
p2.x_range = p1.x_range
p2.scatter(x='t', y='x', source=source)
p3 = figure(tools=tools)
p3.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source)
p = gridplot([[p1, p2, p3]])
show(p)
```

When zooming on p1, p2 "follows" (and vice versa). Is there a way to make p3 follow too, so that p3 only shows the data points that are shown in p1 and p2?

Comment: Since your plots have a common axis (time 't'), a) why not arrange them vertically, underneath each other? That would make the cross-selection more visually intuitive. Or b) you could plot both x,y with different markers and colors on the same plot (left y-axis for series 'x', right y-axis for series 'y')

Comment: Also here's a bug: your individual subplots p1,p2,p3 have toolbars, but when composited with `gridplot`, the toolbars disappear. Even though it's supposed to have a default `merge_tools=True`. I'm using 1.4.0 (I can't see any related issue at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+merge_tools)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra x-axis like in this code (Bokeh v1.0.4). Or if you like you could use time for the main axis in the 3rd plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LinearAxis, DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.models.tickers import YearsTicker
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot

t = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods = 10, freq = 'H')
x = np.linspace(0, 5, len(t))
y = x ** 2
source = ColumnDataSource({'t': t, 'x': x, 'y': y})
tools = "pan,box_select,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"

p1 = figure(tools = tools, x_axis_type = 'datetime', active_scroll = 'wheel_zoom')
p1.scatter(x = 't', y = 'x', source = source)

p2 = figure(tools = tools, x_axis_type = 'datetime')
p2.x_range = p1.x_range
p2.scatter(x = 't', y = 'x', source = source)

p3 = figure(tools = tools)
p3.extra_x_ranges = { "Time": p1.x_range }  # y_range_name = "Volume",
extra_x_axis = LinearAxis(x_range_name = "Time", ticker = YearsTicker())
extra_x_axis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter( days = ["%m/%d %H:%M"],
                                                months = ["%m/%d %H:%M"],
                                                hours = ["%m/%d %H:%M"],
                                                minutes = ["%m/%d %H:%M"])
p3.add_layout(extra_x_axis, place = 'below')
p3.scatter(x = 'x', y = 'y', x_range_name = "Time", source = source)

layout = gridplot([[p1, p2, p3]])

show(layout)
```

Result:

[image]